# Need guidance on best practices for keeping react/redux login code clean

Tags: reactjs, redux, action, reducers

I am working on a react/redux app with a Nodejs server and Mongo database. I have the functioning login code for my react/redux side that successfully passes to the server and logs in the user. It just seems overly lengthy and in need of refactoring to condense it. I realize there is a million ways to refactor boilerplate, but I would appreciate if anyone could point me to areas to make my loginAction code and loginReducer code more elegant.

The following are the Login.js page using a redux-form component, the loginActions.js, actionTypes.js, and loginReducer.js files. The login functions correctly and touches the database with the email/password combo to result in the return of a the authUser data.

Login.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import "./Register.scss";
import LoginForm from "../../components/Forms/AuthForms/LoginForm";
import * as actions from "../../store/actions/authActions/loginActions";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";

    class Login extends Component {
      state = {
        email: "",
        password: "",
      };

      handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
          email: event.email,
          password: event.password,
        });
      };

      handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let user = {
          email: this.state.email,
          password: this.state.password,
        };
        console.log("submit", user);

        this.props.onLogin(user);
        console.log("click");
      };
      render() {
        console.log();

        return (
          <Container className="form">
            <Row className="form-row">
              <h3>Login</h3>
              <LoginForm
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                user={this.user}
              />
            </Row>
          </Container>
        );
      }
    }

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log(state);
  return {
    loading: state.login.loading,
    authUser: state.login.authUser,
    token: state.login.token,
    isAuth: state.login.isAuth,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onLogin: (user) => dispatch(actions.loginUser(user)),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

loginActions.js

```
import * as actionTypes from "../types";
import axios from "axios";

export const loginStart = () => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.LOGIN_START,
  };
};

export const loginSuccess = (token, authUser) => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    token,
    authUser,
  };
};

export const loginFail = (error) => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.LOGIN_FAIL,
    error: error,
  };
};

export const logout = () => {
  localStorage.removeItem("token");
  localStorage.removeItem("authUser");
  return {
    type: actionTypes.LOGOUT,
  };
};

export const loginUser = (user) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(loginStart());
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:3100/auth/login", user)
      .then((response) => {
        /* This is an artifact of the way the authController returns the MongoDB doc.
        Needs fixing in authController. Also, need to remove password from return MongoDB doc
        for authUser.
        */
        let authUser = response.data.user._doc;
        localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
        localStorage.setItem("authUser", JSON.stringify(authUser));
        dispatch(loginSuccess(response.data.token, authUser));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        dispatch(loginFail(error));
      });
  };
};

export const setLoginRedirect = (path) => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.SET_LOGIN_REDIRECT,
    path,
  };
};
```

loginReducer.js

```
import * as actionTypes from "../../actions/types";
import { updateObject } from "../../../shared/utility";
/* upDateObject export code
      export const updateObject = (oldObject, newValues) => {
          return {
              ...oldObject,
              ...newValues
          };
      };
*/
const initialState = {
  token: localStorage.getItem("token") || null,
  authUser: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("authUser")) || {},
  isAuth: false,
  error: null,
  loading: false,
  loginRedirectPath: "/dashboard",
};

const loginStart = (state, action) => {
  return updateObject(state, {
    error: null,
    loading: true,
  });
};

const loginSuccess = (state, action) => {
  return updateObject(state, {
    token: action.token,
    authUser: action.authUser,
    error: null,
    loading: false,
    isAuth: true,
  });
};

const loginFail = (state, action) => {
  return updateObject(state, {
    error: action.error,
    loading: false,
  });
};

const logout = (state, action) => {
  return updateObject(state, {
    token: null,
    authData: null,
    isAuth: false,
  });
};

const setLoginRedirect = (state, action) => {
  return updateObject(state, { loginRedirectPath: action.path });
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.LOGIN_START:
            return loginStart(state, action)
        case actionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            return loginSuccess(state, action)
        case actionTypes.LOGIN_FAIL:
            return loginFail(state, action)
        case actionTypes.LOGOUT:
            return logout(state, action)
        case actionTypes.SET_LOGIN_REDIRECT:
            return setLoginRedirect(state, action)
        default: return state
    };
};

export default reducer;
```

So if anyone has any pointers as to where I can shorten my code, I would appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Login.js**

```js
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    //rest of the code
    e.preventDefault()
    const user = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,
    }
    this.props.dispatch(loginUser(user, () => this.props.history.push("/dashboard")))
  }
```

Instead of having multiple actions for login success, login fail, etc, I would use a single `loginUser` function which returns a function that dispatches actions, a.k.a `thunk`.

**loginActions.js**

```js
export const loginUser = (user, redirect) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: actionTypes.loginStart })
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(`${url}/auth/login`, user)
      dispatch({
        type: actionTypes.loginSuccess,
        data: { authUser: res.data.user._doc }
      })
      localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.token)
      localStorage.setItem("authUser", JSON.stringify(res.data.authUser));
      redirect()
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: actionTypes.loginFail,
        data: { error },
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Redirect the user to dashboard after login is successful.

For logout, you can add the logout actions just like you did in your code above.

---

**loginReducer.js**

```js
const initialState = {
  token: localStorage.getItem("token") || null,
  authUser: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("authUser")) || {},
  isAuth: false,
  error: null,
  loading: false,
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.loginStart:
      return {
            ...state,
            loading: true,
            isAuth: false
            error: null
        }
    case actionTypes.loginSuccess:
        return {
            ...state,
            loading: false,
            isAuth: true
            authUser: action.authUser
            token: action.token
            error: null
        }
    case actionTypes.loginFail:
        return {
            ...state,
            loading: false,
            error: action.error
        }
        default: return state
    };
};


const reducer
export default reducer
```

IMO, that's still a lot of code. If you further want to "clean" it, there's a new package called [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) that pretty much solves the boilerplate problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is so hard to follow what is really necessary in some cases as the npm tools and newer js tools keep advancing. I guess it is good practice to "write it long hand" then focus on cleaning it up. Although, it does take time. I appreciate your time in helping me with this. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, mate. Keep enjoying and keep learning. Cheers!! Do mark or hit the upvote button if you find this helpful.